# Need assistance with a SQL query to find percentage share

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MYSQL to run my sql queries

Below is the structure of the table

Table-1: job_data

job_id: unique identifier of jobs

actor_id: unique identifier of actor

event: decision/skip/transfer

language: language of the content

time_spent: time spent to review the job in seconds

org: organization of the actor

ds: date in the yyyy/mm/dd format. It is stored in the form of text and we use presto to run. no need for date function

Dataset:

| dates | job_id | actor_id | event | language | time_spent | org |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11/30/2020 | 21 | 1001 | skip | English | 15 | A |
| 11/30/2020 | 22 | 1006 | transfer | Arabic | 25 | B |
| 11/29/2020 | 23 | 1003 | decision | Persian | 20 | C |
| 11/28/2020 | 23 | 1005 | transfer | Persian | 22 | D |
| 11/28/2020 | 25 | 1002 | decision | Hindi | 11 | B |
| 11/27/2020 | 11 | 1007 | decision | French | 104 | D |
| 11/26/2020 | 23 | 1004 | skip | Persian | 56 | A |
| 11/25/2020 | 20 | 1003 | transfer | Italian | 45 | C |

I am trying to find percentage share of each language: Share of each language for different contents. Calculate the percentage share of each language in the last 30 days?

My Query

```
SELECT language,
ROUND(100.0 * SUM(IF(event IN ('transfer', 'decision'), 1, 0)) / COUNT(job_id), 2) AS percentage_share
FROM job_data
WHERE ds BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY language;
```

0 rows returned

I am not getting any result whatsoever

Comment: If you're storing the dates in text format, you need to use `STR_TO_DATE()` to parse it unless it's in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

Comment: You say the dates are in `yyyy/mm/dd` format, but the dataset you show is in `mm/dd/yyyy` format. Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the dates since they're not stored in the format that MySQL can parse automatically.

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(ds, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN ...
```

Comment: I used the below query but still there is no row returned, so just want to confirm whether the logic is correct as per the dataset provided

{SELECT language,
ROUND(100.0 * SUM(IF(event IN ('transfer', 'decision','skip'), 1, 0)) / COUNT(job_id), 2) AS percentage_share
FROM sql_project_1
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(ds, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY language;

Comment: Please post table data as text so I can copy and paste it into a test database. The screenshot in the question is useless for that.

Comment: https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables

ds job_id actor_id event language   time_spent org
11/30/2020 21 1001 skip      English       15             A
11/30/2020 22 1006 transfer Arabic      25             B
11/29/2020 23 1003 decision Persian      20             C
11/28/2020 23 1005 transfer Persian      22             D
11/28/2020 25 1002 decision Hindi     11             B
11/27/2020 11 1007 decision French    104             D
11/26/2020 23 1004 skip        Persian     56             A
11/25/2020 20 1003 transfer Italian     45             C

Comment: Put it in the question as a formatted table.

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support for table markdown syntax

Comment: The character limit is not letting me enter the dataset in formatted table but I have provided a link where you can paste the text and it will generate the table

Comment: None of the dates are in the past week or month. Change the date range to include the dates in the table.